# Difference between adding a local file dependency and a repository in gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

In gradle we can add a local repository for jars which is not present in your central repository.

```
repositories{
    flatDir {
        dirs "lib"
    } 
}
```

There is also a way to add a local file dependency like

```
testRuntime files("my.jar")
```

What is the difference between the 2 approaches? When can one be preferred over another?